# An issue with uart and pic 18f452

Tags: serial-port, pic, uart, mikroc

i have a problem with pic18f452 and uart
i use simplest code like that:

```
 UART1_Init(9600);              // Initialize UART module at 9600 bps
 Delay_ms(100);                 // Wait for UART module to stabilize
```

and between forever while loop i have this code

```
  UART1_Write_Text("HELLO2");
  Delay_ms(1000);
```

also i have in my hardware lcd module it works very fine but my received data on pc
is a scrap like that

```
???m
```

i have checked all connection sothand time nothing wrong also i have changed MAX232 ic but with no luck ?!
my hardware is like that
[image]

finall all my connections are ok (polarity and every thing else ?)
EDIT : i use mikroc as a compiler

Comment: For beginning send only a single character (byte) like 0x55 and tell as what you are receiving on PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a baud rate error. Have you checked that your oscillator settings are resulting in the expected frequency? Does the serial library you are using expect a certain clock frequency and you are sure that you are running at that frequency, or does it work over a set of frequencies and you have correctly informed the serial library what frequency you are using? Also it would be useful to see the byte received as a decimal or hex number rather than just ASCII.

Comment: ok i will try this with pic 16f877a since 18f452 have it's own setting for internal and external clock usage ! ! (it's very confusing with mikroc !)

Comment: ok i found the problem finally it's related with oscillator as you mentioned :D

Answer (score 0):

What about the start bits, number of data bits, parity, and stop bits? Are they the same on both ends?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you have loose connections i.e. from max 232 to Pic & from max 232 to PC.
Try checking the fluctuations over the transmit pin or usr Oscilloscope to see the ASCII values of Hello World alphabets.